# Ubuntu 22.04 server, Intel x550, advertised speed not correct

Tags: networking, drivers, server, intel, 22.04

The network card Intel X550T installed on an Ubuntu server 22.04 does not advertise all the available speeds, therefore (if that is the reason) the auto-negotiation fails to connect to the speed available (the source is a 2.5GB connection):

```
Supported link modes:   100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
                        10000baseT/Full
                        2500baseT/Full
                        5000baseT/Full
Supported pause frame use: Symmetric
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Supported FEC modes: Not reported
Advertised link modes:  100baseT/Full
                        1000baseT/Full
                        10000baseT/Full
Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
Speed: 1000Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Auto-negotiation: on
```

What should I do, after looking for solutions it seems to be a driver issue, but on the other hand it seems that the kernel in Ubuntu 22.04 should fully support this card ?

Edit:
Following @waltinator suggestions, I modified the speed of the card by running:

```
sudo ethtool -s <name_of_card> speed 2500
```

The command above raises the speed to 2.5GB as expected.
However, I could not turn off the auto-negotiation (which seems recommended from @waltinator comment); if I run the command:

```
 sudo ethtool -s <name_of_card> autoneg off speed 2500 duplex full
```

or:

```
sudo ethtool -s <name_of_card> autoneg off speed 2500
```

or:

```
sudo ethtool -s <name_of_card> autoneg off
```

there is no error but no effect, speed and auto-negotiation are not changed.

Edit 2:
After some testing, changing the link mode with the command above leads to random disconnections.
Maybe turning auto-negotiation off would solve this, but trying to turn off auto-negotiation on the card has no effect (I suppose the auto-negotiation parameter cannot be turned off on the card if the switch requires auto-negotiation, and I am not allowed to change that on the switch).

Comment: Turn OFF autonegotiation. Set the speed you insist on. If you know the speed you want, and know both ends can do the speed, there is no need to negotiate. Long ago, I saw a connection that spent all its time re-re-re-autonegotiating and almost none of the time sending data. Read `man ip ip-device ip-link`.

Comment: I can increase the speed and it works as expected, but if I do 'sudo ethtool -s <name_of_card> autoneg off' it has no effect (I keep getting: 'Auto-negotiation: on'). And how should I make these changes persistent in Ubuntu 22.04 ?

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: You did not ask any question in your comments but suggested a solution, which I tried, and then informed you of the result. But my question is unchanged, I would like to know if there is a best practice solution to that issue, and if yes, what it is in detail.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Ubuntu 22.04 Server, the following command advertises all speeds available and solves the issue:

```
ethtool -s <ethX> advertise 0x1800000001028
```

This is detailed in the documentation of the Intel drivers for Linux ("ixgbe"); but you do not need to install them, the card works directly out of the box with Ubuntu 22.04 Server.

Comment: Wow, you really saved me! I've been trying to get this issue resolved for 2+ days! I tried updating BIOS, NIC firmware, tried different network switches, etc. I was getting ready to return my motherboard. Thank you so much!